On constructing a form on manifold with non-zero vector fields.

The text above is from "Introduction to Symplectic Topology" pp.243. I'm confused about the construction of $\alpha$ part in the proof. In this step authors assumes that $M$ allows for a free $\mathbb{S}^1$-action and $X$ is the induced vector field.

is $\iota(X)d\alpha=0$ an empty condition? as $\alpha$ is a form, $d\alpha$ is already $0$.
To construct a form with $\alpha(X)=1$: Take an open cover, by Peano existence theorem there is a local coordinate system that $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_0}}$, then we can take $\alpha=d x_0$ then use decomposition of unit to glue them to a global form. But this looks complicated, are there simpler arguments?


It is a bad idea to begin a post with a quote that is utterly unclear because it assumes some things that are not quoted. Like: what action  of what group on what space ??? ... together with the fact that even after the quoted material, you neglect to explain anything about what it means.

@DanAsimov I agree the post isn't the most clear, but the questions being asked do not require you to understand the statement of the lemma.

But you should never include anything in your post that is unclear. People should not be asked to figure out which parts of a post they need to understand, and which parts are incomprehensible nonsense that they should ignore.


I don't see why we would have $d\alpha = 0$ since $\alpha$ is not assumed to be closed.
For every point $p \in M$, choose a small neighborhood $U_p$ and a form $\alpha_p \in \Omega^1(U_p)$ such that $\alpha_p(X_p) = 1$ (note that I am only requiring that this equality hold at a single point). By shrinking $U_p$, we may assume $\alpha_p(X_q) > 0$ for all $q \in U_p$. Then rescale $\alpha_p$ so that $\alpha_p(X_q) = 1$ holds for all $q \in U_p$. Now use a partition of unity argument with the cover $\{U_p\}_{p \in M}$ to define $\alpha$ globally.

Edit: Here is another solution for (2). Pick a Riemannian metric, and let $\alpha = X^\flat / \|X\|^2$. Here $\flat$ denotes the musical isomorphism determined by the metric.

I see what's wrong, I'm assuming $\alpha$ is closed. By the way, did my construction of closed form correct? It would simplifies the computation in latter steps.

@PeterWu I don't think your construction gives you a closed form because you are using a partition of unity. For instance, if $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are closed forms, for two functions $\rho_1, \rho_2$, the linear combination $\rho_1\omega_1 + \rho_2\omega_2$ may not be closed.

thanks, now I understand why author constructs such $\alpha$
